# A cycle was detected in a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

For my below query in LINQ I am getting an error when executing.

> A cycle was detected in a LINQ expression

```
    var data = db.hdr.Where(m => m.created_by == created_id && m.client_id == client_id)
.OrderBy(m => m.request_id).AsQueryable();

    data = from d in db.dtls
           from h in data
           where (d.request_id == h.request_id && d.employee_id == "005")
           select h;
```

I am getting error at the second line `data =from....`

I am not able to solve the issue. Please help me.

Comment: On which line do you get the error? on "var data = .." or on "data = from ..." ?

Comment: @StevenLemmens i am getting error at `data = from`

Comment: @downvoter please tell me why

Comment: Check the duplicate question they tagged for you. It contains a great explanation in the accepted answer. Post back if you have any more questions about that!

Comment: @stevenlemmens i checked that since im new to linq can't understand fully.. so i cannot do the code as above..confused how to filter the AsQueryable() then

Comment: All you have to do is don't use the variable "data" a second time. Use a different variable to store the result of your second query. Because in your second query you have a reference to "data", which by the time the query gets executed is overwritten with your second query. So your second query has a reference to itself, hence the cycle exception message.

try doing var data2 = from d ...

Comment: @stevenLemmens thanks a lot mate..pblm solved..don't know hw to say thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. You can always upvote my comment which helped you by using the little arrow that points up when you hover over my comment to show it helped you. It may help someone else too in the future that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86761/discussion-between-sachu-and-steven-lemmens).